# PostgreSQL Driver Appends Hidden Characters On Some SQL Statements

Tags: sql, spring, postgresql, insert, syntax-error

I have an application that I am building (Spring Boot, PostgreSQL); I am executing sql statements from a file sqlStatements.sql against the database. In some instances, it appears that the driver is appending a white-space character to the front of insert statements and when trying to create a function, it does not occur when defining tables though. I used the trim() method on the sql string to no avail. When logging the sql statements, there is no white-space character, but when looking at the PostgreSQL logs, sure enough, it's there. Is this a known issue with the driver? Is there a setting on the database side I need to change? Or do I need to do extract work in Java to avoid this error?

The space disappeared when pasting it here, so I added it; the sql files are all UTF-8.

Application log:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near
>   "insert"   Position: 1

PostgreSQL log:

> 2017-03-04 10:29:26 EST ERROR:  syntax error at or near " insert" at
>   character 1

Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: I highly doubt that that is the actual issue. I would suspect that there is something wrong with your queries or the way you are reading your queries prior to executing them.

Comment: The queries work in pgAdmin, and there's no difference between the way im reading the files with create statement vs insert statements.

Comment: Your SQL file probably starts with a BOM. Remove it from the file, or deal with it when reading it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark. Dump each and every character read from the file, and you'll see that there *is* a nin-printable character in what you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the file encoding was different between the various sql files. I had to set the encoding to "UTF-8" instead of "UTF-8 with BOM".

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46586/textedit-removes-byte-order-mark-bom-from-unicode-utf-files-how-to-fix